# Can an "Into" statement write multiple results to a column type variable?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function that declares a variable like this:

```
FUNCTION functionName((input_value) IN INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER IS

...
value_key_in   (database_name)(table_name).value_key%type;
```

And it writes to this value with this Select statement:

```
select value_key
into value_key_in
from (table)
where (Conditions);
```

If (conditions) returns more than one valid result for Value_Key, will "value_key_in" be able to hold them all?

Comment: yes, it is possible, what rdms?

Comment: @IlyaBursov rdms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system

Comment: @IlyaBursov Oracle

Comment: pl/sql is language, used by Oracle RDBMS

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html

Comment: @IlyaBursov That doesn't sound like it would work then: "If the SELECT statement identifies more than one row to be fetched, Oracle Database will raise the TOO_MANY_ROWS exception."

Comment: `Using the Cursor FOR Loop`

Comment: @IlyaBursov Well, that's exactly what I was looking for!  Sorry I didn't recognize it right away - I'm trying to fill in for our usual Oracle expert, and I'm only really familiar with querying and simple SQL programs.

Answer (score 1):

select into will throw TOO_MANY_ROWS error. if you want to store multiple results of a select query use cursor.

eg: `open cur_values for
    select value_key
    from (table)
    where (Conditions);`

will carry all the records that match the select query.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If you expect to get more records from the query, you may use either a loop over result set or BULK COLLECT clause.

With BULK COLLECT you are able to fetch more records into a PL/SQL collection.

See the following example (from [this OTN article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html)) and note `l_employees` data type:

```
PROCEDURE process_all_rows
IS
   TYPE employees_aat 
   IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   l_employees employees_aat;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_employees
      FROM employees;

   FOR indx IN 1 .. l_employees.COUNT 
   LOOP
       analyze_compensation 
      (l_employees(indx));
   END LOOP;
END process_all_rows;
```

See also this article: [Bulk Processing with BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html).